# In Laravel, does anyone have a list of which Facades point to which class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Does anyone have a list of which Facades point to which Classes? Something I can use as a quick reference so I don't have to keep tracing my way through the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Facade Class Reference

> - **App** - [*Illuminate\Foundation\Application*](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.html)  app
> - **Artisan** - [*Illuminate\Console\Application*](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Console/Application.html) artisan
> - **Auth** - [*Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager*](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.html)   auth
> - **Auth (Instance)** - [*Illuminate\Auth\Guard*](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html)
> - **Blade** - [*Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler*](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html)  blade.compiler
> - and so on...

[**Here is the entire list**](http://laravel.com/docs/facades#facade-class-reference)

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice that was added to the official documentation.